# Retaining 2 previous versions of a log file

Tags: java, java.util.logging

My Java application CB gets data from a database, say "Case 1." Each time CB starts is creates a logfile:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("CBLog");  
fh = new FileHandler(CBDataPath + "\\CB.log";
logger.addHandler(fh);
SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();  
fh.setFormatter(formatter);  
logger.info("CB started");
```

I would like to keep 2 previous versions of the log file for a particular case. How can this most easily be done?

Here's one idea I have. I could maintain an integer representing the run number in the Case database. Each successive run names the log file CB_CaseA_n.log where n is the previous run number plus 1. Each time the CB is run on CaseA the CasaA directory is searched for all CB_CaseA_?.log files and only the 3 most recent files kept. I.e., on run 10 of CB_CaseA_7 would be deleted. Doesn't seem very elegant.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

From the [java.util.logging.FileHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html):

> count specifies how many output files to cycle through (defaults to 1).
>
> "%g" the generation number to distinguish rotated logs

Create a FileHandler with count and generation pattern:

```
new FileHandler("CBDataPath + "\\CB%g.log, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 2, false);
```

Comment: Thanks! Diabolically, I just finished my own hack! I'll try your suggestion though.

Comment: And sorry about the code formatting, or rather, lack thereof. I spaced in 4 and then pasted... guess it didn't work.

Comment: Oops. Seems to be a problem. In addition to creating CB0.log it creates CB0.log.lck. The latter is deleted when the program completes. My understanding it this means the log file already existed in another process. I just used your new FileHandler line (with slight corrections" in place of mine.

Comment: @EdS Every open file handler will have dot 'lck' file.  On close, that 'lck' file is deleted.

Comment: I don't think this is what I want after all. Javadoc says it starts writing to the next file when the current one exceeds "limit" in size. My desire is to keep separate logs for each of specified number of app sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. The explanation:

```
updateLogHistory() maintains historical log files in the MyConcourses directory. It is called in the ConcoursGUI() constructor.

The intuition is a "stack" of log files with the current log, i.e., ConcoursBuilderLog_0.log,  on top. To make room for a new log file
 for the ConcoursBuilder session, any existing log files have to be "pushed down." However, the stack is allowed to hold only a prescribed
number, size, elements so if there are already size files in the stack the bottom one gets deleted, or rather, overwritten. When the function
 finishes the top TWO will be identical, so the top one can be overwritten in the caller.

It's important to note that "stack" is a metaphor here; there isn't a stack in the sense of a programed data structure. There can be only 
size log files in the MyConcourses folder. What actually happens in a so-called push is the CONTENTS of ConcoursBuilderLog_i.log
```

gets copied into ConcoursBuilderLog_i+1.log, leaving  ConcoursBuilderLog_i.log unchanged.

```
// The algorithm below requires an initial ConcoursBuilder_0.log. Consequently, prior to calling updateLogHistory() 
// the directory is first checked and an empty one is created if absent. Typically, this happens only in the first 
// run after INSTALLATION of ConcoursBuilder. However, it must be checked because the user might accidently deleted it.
//
// Work from the bottom up to push all existing log files down, leaving the contents of the current ConcoursBuilderLog_0 in
// both ConcoursBuilderLog_0 and 1. the subsequent log file will overwrite both ConcoursBuilderLog_0.
//



Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("ConcoursBuilderLog"); 
File logFile = null;
try {
    String strFileFullPath = concoursBuilderDataPath + "\\ConcoursBuilderLog_" + 0 + ".log";
    logFile = new File(strFileFullPath);
    if(!logFile.exists()){
        try {
            logFile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ConcoursGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try {            
            Files.write(Paths.get(logFile.getPath()), "Empty log file".getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ConcoursGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    // Maintain a "stack" of historical ConcoursBuilder log files.
    updateLogHistory(NUM_SAVED_LOGS,  logFile);  

} catch (SecurityException e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
} 
fhLogger = null;
try {
    fhLogger = new FileHandler(logFile.toString(), false);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(ConcoursGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (SecurityException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(ConcoursGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
logger.addHandler(fhLogger);
logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
fhLogger.setFormatter(formatter);

// the updater
private static  void updateLogHistory(int size, File logFile0){
        String strTemp = logFile0.toString(); 
    String strPrefix = strTemp.substring(0, strTemp.indexOf("_")+1);
    for(int i =  size-1; i >=0; i--){
        String strFileFullPath = strPrefix + i + ".log";
        File logFile_i  = new File(strFileFullPath);
        if(logFile_i.exists() && !logFile_i.isDirectory()){
            Path path= Paths.get(strFileFullPath); // this is the the absolute path to the i file as a Path                
            if( i != size-1){
                // not at the end so there is a valid file name i+1.
                // Note that the file selected by iNext has already been pushed into iNext+1, or is the last. Either way,
                // it can properly be overwritten.
                int iPlus1 = i + 1;
                String strFileFullPathIPlus1 = strPrefix + iPlus1 + ".log";
                Path pathIPlus1 = Paths.get(strFileFullPathIPlus1); //  absolute path to the file as a Path                
                try {
                    Files.copy(path, pathIPlus1,   REPLACE_EXISTING);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    okDialog("IOException while updating log history in updateLogHistory()");
                    Logger.getLogger(ConcoursGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                continue; // (unnecessary) branch back to for() 
            } else{
                // Getting here means stack is full. IOW, the reference file the is last log file to be kept so we no longer need it's contents.
                // No action required since it will simply be overwritten in the next pass.
                //  things in the next pass.;
            }
        } 
    }

}
```